# ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql

i want to add some details on my table but it shows me this ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction. there is only two column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PjK2.png)

insert into city (name) values ("delhi"),("mumbai"),("tamil nadu"),("kerela");